# Simplify this indices?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

Simplify this:

$6a^3 * {a^{-5}\over2}$

I got $6a^3 * {1\over2a^5}$

What should I do next? please explain with steps.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  Now divide $6$ by $2$ and use the laws of exponents on the terms with $a$.

Comment: is it $3a^{-2}$ ?

Comment: @Helena. Yes, it is !